# Is the series comparison criterion for convergence valid for absolute convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm studying the convergence and absolute convergence of the series of functions defined by the sequence of functions:
\begin{equation*}
f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\phantom{1000}x \mapsto \sin\left(\dfrac{x}{n^2}\right).
\end{equation*}

I prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{equation*}
\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{n^2}\right)\right| \le \dfrac{|x|}{n^2},
\end{equation*}

and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left|x\right|}{n^2}$ is absolut convergent, does it means that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\sin(\frac{x}{n^2})$ is absolute convergent?

And if it is why can I apply this?

Comment: Do you know the Comparison Test?

Comment: Thanks :) @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just apply Comparision test